# Can't send message to all sockets (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Heya I'm trying to build a small chat client to learn how websockets work in order to make a game in canvas. It works great with sending sockets but they are only sending it to the the one who wrote it.

I guess I've missed something small, but I can't understand why it won't work.

**Server side code**

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('user-message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    sendMessage(data.message);
  });
});

var sendMessage = function(message) {
      io.sockets.emit('server-message', {message: message});
}
```

**Client side code**

```
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

            socket.on('server-message', function (data) {
                var history = $('#chatbox').val();

                $('#chatbox').val(history + "\n" + data.message)
            });


            $("#write").keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    socket.emit('user-message', {message: $(this).val()});
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `socket.broadcast.emit` to send a message to all other sockets.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('user-message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        sendMessage.call(socket, data.message);
    });
});
var sendMessage = function(message) {
      this.emit('server-message', {message: message});
      this.broadcast.emit('server-message', {message: message});
}
```

Comment: It didn't work either I'm afraid. Just sends it back to whoever sent it in the first place. I actually tried broadcast before and thought io.sockets.emit would help since it's all sockets.

Comment: @cubsink did you call `broadcast.emit` on the individual socket?

Comment: I don't think so, I copied your code. And I've tried to change this to io.sockets.

Comment: @cubsink try replacing your `io.sockets.on` call and `sendMessage` function with what I have in the answer and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean. Can you clarify? My code looks entirely as your answer.

Comment: I've noticed something weird and its that console.log wont output anything if it is inside socket.on on the server side. But it has to run since the output get registered in the client.

Comment: Found the problem now.. I don't think it ever was something wrong with my code. The client connects with localhost, where I had a server up in the background without noticing. Because I tried it there first and then I moved all my code to my other server to continue with some functionality so other may join. Dang, what an annoying mistake.